# Exception: Prelude.head: empty list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I have already read all the questions already asked about this error and I don't have any of those issues. Can someone please help. The comments are the hard code for the given example so we can use a top-down approach. When I get done with a function I comment out the hard code. I have only implemented the first 2 functions. In ghci when you run the file, type 'main', if it prints true the code is working. When I test both functions separately they return true but together they return the above error.

```
import Data.List ((\\), sort)

type Board = [[Int]]

inputBoard :: Board
inputBoard = 
    [[5,3,0, 0,7,0, 0,0,0],
     [6,0,0, 1,9,5, 0,0,0],
     [0,9,8, 0,0,0, 0,6,0],
     [8,0,0, 0,6,0, 0,0,3],
     [4,0,0, 8,0,3, 0,0,1],
     [7,0,0, 0,2,0, 0,0,6],
     [0,6,0, 0,0,0, 2,8,0],
     [0,0,0, 4,1,9, 0,0,5],
     [0,0,0, 0,8,0, 0,7,9]]

solvedBoard :: Board
solvedBoard = 
    [[5,3,4, 6,7,8, 9,1,2],
     [6,7,2, 1,9,5, 3,4,8],
     [1,9,8, 3,4,2, 5,6,7],
     [8,5,9, 7,6,1, 4,2,3],
     [4,2,6, 8,5,3, 7,9,1],
     [7,1,3, 9,2,4, 8,5,6],
     [9,6,1, 5,3,7, 2,8,4],
     [2,8,7, 4,1,9, 6,3,5],
     [3,4,5, 2,8,6, 1,7,9]]

type Coords = (Int,Int)
type BoardElement = (Coords,Int)

inputBoardElements :: [BoardElement]
inputBoardElements = 
    [((0,0),5),((0,1),3),((0,4),7),((1,0),6),((1,3),1),((1,4),9),((1,5),5),
     ((2,1),9),((2,2),8),((2,7),6),((3,0),8),((3,4),6),((3,8),3),((4,0),4),
     ((4,3),8),((4,5),3),((4,8),1),((5,0),7),((5,4),2),((5,8),6),((6,1),6),
     ((6,6),2),((6,7),8),((7,3),4),((7,4),1),((7,5),9),((7,8),5),((8,4),8),
     ((8,7),7),((8,8),9)]

inputBoardEmpty :: [Coords]
inputBoardEmpty = 
    [(0,2),(0,3),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(1,1),(1,2),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),
     (2,0),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(2,8),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,5),(3,6),
     (3,7),(4,1),(4,2),(4,4),(4,6),(4,7),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,5),(5,6),
     (5,7),(6,0),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,8),(7,0),(7,1),(7,2),(7,6),
     (7,7),(8,0),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(8,5),(8,6)]

solvedBoardElements :: [BoardElement]
solvedBoardElements = 
    [((0,0),5),((0,1),3),((0,2),4),((0,3),6),((0,4),7),((0,5),8),((0,6),9),
     ((0,7),1),((0,8),2),((1,0),6),((1,1),7),((1,2),2),((1,3),1),((1,4),9),
     ((1,5),5),((1,6),3),((1,7),4),((1,8),8),((2,0),1),((2,1),9),((2,2),8),
     ((2,3),3),((2,4),4),((2,5),2),((2,6),5),((2,7),6),((2,8),7),((3,0),8),
     ((3,1),5),((3,2),9),((3,3),7),((3,4),6),((3,5),1),((3,6),4),((3,7),2),
     ((3,8),3),((4,0),4),((4,1),2),((4,2),6),((4,3),8),((4,4),5),((4,5),3),
     ((4,6),7),((4,7),9),((4,8),1),((5,0),7),((5,1),1),((5,2),3),((5,3),9),
     ((5,4),2),((5,5),4),((5,6),8),((5,7),5),((5,8),6),((6,0),9),((6,1),6),
     ((6,2),1),((6,3),5),((6,4),3),((6,5),7),((6,6),2),((6,7),8),((6,8),4),
     ((7,0),2),((7,1),8),((7,2),7),((7,3),4),((7,4),1),((7,5),9),((7,6),6),
     ((7,7),3),((7,8),5),((8,0),3),((8,1),4),((8,2),5),((8,3),2),((8,4),8),
     ((8,5),6),((8,6),1),((8,7),7),((8,8),9)]

main :: IO ()
main = print (sudoku inputBoard == solvedBoard)  

sudoku :: Board -> Board
sudoku [] = []
sudoku b =
    let bde = fst (toElements b)
        cd = snd (toElements b)
        allboards = sudokuElements [bde] cd
    in fromElements (head allboards)

--sudoku b 
    --| b == inputBoard = solvedBoard
    --| otherwise = error "sudoku not implemented"

sudokuElements :: [[BoardElement]] -> [Coords] -> [[BoardElement]]
sudokuElements a [] = a
sudokuElements [] _ = []
sudokuElements (be:bes) (cd:cds) =
    let xs = validVals be cd
        temp = [[(cd,x)] | x <- xs]
    in sudokuElements temp cds

-- | head bes == inputBoardElements && empty == inputBoardEmpty = 
--     [solvedBoardElements]
-- | otherwise = error "sudokuElements not implemented"

validVals :: [BoardElement] -> Coords -> [Int]
validVals bes rc
    | bes == tail solvedBoardElements && rc==(8,6) = [1]
    | bes \\ solvedBoardElements == [] = [1..9]
    | otherwise = []

toElements :: Board -> ([BoardElement],[Coords])
toElements b 
    | b==inputBoard = (inputBoardElements, inputBoardEmpty)    
    | otherwise = error "toElements not implemented"


fromElements :: [BoardElement] -> Board
fromElements bes 
    | sort bes == solvedBoardElements = solvedBoard
    | otherwise = error "fromElements not implemented"
```

Comment: I'm using top - down approach so I haven't written the code for validVals (although I do know what it will do and what are it's inputs and outputs)

Comment: Given that there are no uses of `head` in your code, the error you are getting must have come from somewhere else, and your question is currently unanswerable. Post the piece of the code where the error is coming from, which must involve some use of the `head` function.

Comment: @AlexisKing I tested the sudoku function seperately and it wasn't giving me an error so I assumed the error was in the other function.

Comment: I edited the code and the error is still there

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `allBoards`/the call to `sudokuElements` is returning an empty list.

Without seeing the entire program, it's hard to give you an exact reason why this might be.

I recommend avoiding the use of `head` in general as it is a partial function. Instead, use pattern matching.

In your case, this

```
fromElements (head allBoards)
```

can be rewritten as

```
case allBoards of
  [] -> error "allBoards returned an empty list." -- Or whatever
  (first:_) -> fromElements first
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried what you said it is still showing an error (exception: allboards returned an empty list). I can provide the whole code if that will help you help me ( code is not complete though)

Comment: Yes, please provide enough code for it to compile and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I've posted the complete code and explain it in the description

Comment: By calling `sudokuElements` with the first argument always being a list of length 1, and the second argument being a list of length 30, and based on the recursive scheme of the function, it is *not possible* that that function will ever return anything except an empty list. Consequently, calling `head` on the result will *always* cause an exception. It's very difficult for me to follow the logic of the program, but I also suspect there could be something going wrong with the logic of the `validVals` function.

Comment: what do you mean by the first argument always being a list of length 1 and the second a list of length 30?

Comment: When you do this: `sudokuElements [bde] cd`, the list `[bde]` is a single element list, and `cd` has I think ~30 elements in it.